# Write configurations for routes in NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js

how are you guys?

Today I need help with my application in Node, I appreciate if someone can help me.

I have my routes set up on my general configuration file, and all my app.gets are rendering files in the folder views, inside the server folder, just like this:

```
SERVER FOLDER
 |
 |- VIEWS FOLDER WITH THE SEVERAL EJS TEMPLATES
 |  |
 |  -- RESERVATIONS.EJS
 |- CONFIGURATIONFILE.JS
```

So, Just to help you to help me.. i have this get example that are working perfectly:

```
app.get('/reservas', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
        res.render('reservations');
    });
```

I have this two configurations in my file configuration file:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Now, the real problem.

I have a public folder that is a sibling folder of the folder server, and i have this login.ejs and I need to render it in the route /, so i have this:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});
```

but it is not pulling the file inside the public folder..

If anyone can help me, I appreciate it

Comment: Are you using Express4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ejs files must be in views folder. Put your login.ejs file into it. 
And then try

```
         app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.render('login.ejs'); })
```

or

```
    app.route('/').get(function (req, res, next) { res.render('login.ejs'); })
```

if you use Express4.

Comment: like i sad, its pushing inside the views inside the server folder, i need push the login.ejs that are inside the public folder..

Comment: app.set('views', __dirname + '/views') means that all your ejs files should be inside views folder, otherwise you can't push them.

Comment: ok, but if put app.set('views', __dirname + '../public'), its searching server../public, not just public..